# how to include "mt" and "gd" in output file's name?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In Microsoft Visual Studio (i'm using VS2013), one can define the output file name, but, can it be more specific, such as put `mt` in the filename if it's using "MultiThread" (or `/MTd`)? It looks `Boost` do have file names with `mt`, `gd` etc but it's not using visual studio project files so I can't copy.

Comment: Boost names the *import library*, not the output file.  So that when you #include a boost header then you automatically get the link dependency.  It is a good way to avoid linking the wrong library flavor.  Naming the output file is entirely up to you.  Just add another configuration and change the Target Name setting.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to manually change the output name to suit your needs. For instance, if you build with `/MTd`, you can change the output name and prefix the dll/lib name with `mt`.

If you have a lots of projects or configurations which needs to be changed, you may use macros and props. The upfront work is more important. You can define a macro which may take differents value, depeding upon what compilation mode is activated. This variable can then be used to control the output filename.

Some more details about this approach:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#bkmkPropertySheets